# Javascript error: Missing : after property id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the code:

```
window.onload({
    var Country = '<?= $core->HotelData($hid, "country"); ?>';
    var options = document.getElementsByTagName('option');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i ++) {
        if (options[i].type == 'option' && options[i].value == Country) {
            options[i].attr('selected','selected');
        }
    }
});
```

I've been struggling with this for hours now, and figured it'd be better if I sought advice from experts.

UPDATE: Source

```
window.onload({
    var Country = 'United Kingdom';
    var options = document.getElementsByTagName('option');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i ++) {
        if (options[i].type == 'option' && options[i].value == Country) {
            options[i].attr('selected','selected');
        }
    }
});
```

UPDATE#2: Fix
The cause of the problem was mostly my stupidity.. ktnxbai

```
function OnLoad() {
    var Country = "<?= $core->HotelData($hid, "country"); ?>";
    var options = document.getElementsByTagName('option');
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i ++) {
        if (options[i].value == Country) {
            options[i].selected = true;
        }
    }
}

window.onload = OnLoad();
```

Comment: Did you ever check the source code that your PHP script generates? `'<?= $core->HotelData($hid, "country"); ?>'` will break as soon as there's a string with single quote involved…

Comment: @Tomalak The PHP is fine.. @Everyone else window.onload = function() { ... }, window.onload = function() { ... };, and all other variations of that don't work.

Comment: Note that your fix simply executes the `OnLoad` function at the point where it is defined (not on `load`), and that assigning the function's return value (which will be `undefined`) to `window.onload` doesn't do anything useful and could be omitted.

Answer (score 4):

You probably meant to write:

```
window.onload = function() {
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you fix the error:

```
window.onload(function(){
    var Country = '<?= $core->HotelData($hid, "country"); ?>';
    var options = document.getElementsByTagName('option');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i ++) {
        if (options[i].type == 'option' && options[i].value == Country) {
            options[i].attr('selected','selected');
        }
    }
});
```

**However**, you should listen for a `load` event on the `window` object, *not* trigger one. Thus, the correct syntax would be:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var Country = '<?= $core->HotelData($hid, "country"); ?>';
    var options = document.getElementsByTagName('option');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i ++) {
        if (options[i].type == 'option' && options[i].value == Country) {
            options[i].attr('selected','selected');
        }
    }
};
```

OR

jQuerified:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var Country = '<?= $core->HotelData($hid, "country"); ?>';
    $('select option[value="'+Country+'"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Comment: This will fire the onload event, receiving the function as an argument. I don't think this is what George was trying to do...

Comment: In case you missed the difference (took me 3 reads to see it), he added `function()` before the open brace.  This is needed so JS knows you're defining the contents of a function, not an object.

Comment: @DanC: Why do you think that? He is trying to select a default value there, why wouldn't that be what he wants?

Comment: I insist this is not what he meant, look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload

Comment: To assign the event handler for the onload event, the correct syntax is window.onload = fn ; on the other hand, you are proposing to do window.onload(fn).

Comment: @DanC: On a second look, yes, you are right. An event was triggered, not assigned a handler. However, to tell you the truth, I didn't look much at the code. I had faced this error before, and I knew its cause, that's what I fixed. :)

Comment: @George Korac: Please post the code the way it is echoed, without the PHP, maybe your PHP in there echos something wrong. View the source code and update your answer to share it.

Comment: @George Korac: Please change your code to one of the options above, and then try again. You are still using `{}`.

Comment: This answer doesn't work because it never addressed all the problems.  @George Korac, see the other posted answers.

Comment: @Brock Adams: Excuse me, how isn't my jQuery version above addressing all the issues? :)

Comment: @Shef I've tested all of your solutions, none of them worked.. @Brock Adams I've tried the ones that are different, but they're mostly all the same..

Comment: @George Korac: Do you see the same error with the jQuery version?

Comment: @George Korac: Do you have this online somewhere, because it seems like you are using the code the wrong way, or you have an error somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

you are just passing a json object to `window.onload`, which is an event not a function. also, you are trying to use jquery like syntax without a jquery object.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing:

```
window.onload = function(){
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.onload = function(){
    var Country = '<?= $core->HotelData($hid, "country"); ?>';
    var options = document.getElementsByTagName('option');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i ++) {
        if (options[i].value == Country) {
            options[i].selected = true;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass a function to `onLoad`.
2. Fix the for loop.
3. Fix the `attr` call.

Should be:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var Country = '<?= $core->HotelData($hid, "country"); ?>';
    var options = document.getElementsByTagName('option');

    for (var i = options.length - 1;  i >= 0;  --i) {
        if (options[i].type == 'option' && options[i].value == Country) {
            $(options[i]).attr('selected','selected');
        }
    }
}
```